# can not save the curly brackets to database

Tags: php, laravel, brackets

I have a problem when trying to save data in the form of html code and some symbols on the laravel framework.

this code that i want to save:

```
{{ ... }}
```

or

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

if I try to submit, the page becomes blank.

Comment: what error is the console giving?

Comment: Can you post your form, route and controller codes...

Comment: saving where? is it in the database or is it simple to the disk?

Comment: the error on the console does not exist, it's just that when I create a new post with the symbol {{...}}, the page can not be opened, just blank.

Answer (score -1):

use `$request->get()` assign data

```
$posts->title = $request->get('title');
```

If you `dd($request)` you can see all the data

Comment: problem only when i save the data to the database

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $posts = New Post;
       $posts->title = $request->title;
       $posts->description = $request->description;

       return back();
    }

Comment: add in your question

Comment: any posts that have code '{{...}}' can not be opened